# Extracting data from a HashBasedTable (a Guava collection) using index values

Tags: java, collections, guava

I have a method that returns a `HashBasedTable` (from Google's Guava project : https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table)

i'm looking to extract values out of that table, after its been created.

```
import com.google.common.collect.HashBasedTable;
import com.google.common.collect.Table;
/**
 *
 * @author yschellekens
 */
public class StackOverflow {  

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public static Table<Long, Long, String> getGeoTargeting()  {
         Table<Long, Long, String> weightedGraph = HashBasedTable.create();

         weightedGraph.put(999_99_9999L, 999_99_9999L, "blabla");
         return weightedGraph;
 }


   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     Table<Long, Long, String> weightedGraph = HashBasedTable.create();
       weightedGraph=getGeoTargeting();
      System.out.println(weightedGraph.isEmpty());
   }
}
```

output:

```
run:
false
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

My question is: how can i extract a single element from the table, something like (which allows me to extract elements by index):

```
get(int index) //as in array list
```

and not like (this is the only get method in Javadoc for `Hashbasetable`)

```
get(Object rowKey, Object columnKey)
Returns the value corresponding to the given row and column keys, or null if no such mapping exists.
```

Since i want to extract element by indexes and not by values

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about reading the doc ? Or the link you gave us ?

Comment: I Did read it, no sight of other get method's, besides the one that i mentioned

Comment: 1. There's no index. 2. There are *two* keys. 3. A `HashBasedTable` inherits from `Table` which is a **2-dimensional** table. 4. Most probably not what you're looking for. 5. For indexing, use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks, ill take this as an answer, please post it

Comment: @Dici, i Seriously dont understant these nasty comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve all values in your table as a collection do this:

```
Collection values = weightedGraph.values()
```

To access any value in the returned collection by index do this:

```
new ArrayList(values).get(index);
```